# Is running this command twice going to cause an issue?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, terminal

> In computing, tee is a command in various command-line interpreters (shells) such as Unix shells, 4DOS/4NT and Windows PowerShell, which displays or pipes the output of a command and copies it into a file or a variable. It is primarily used in conjunction with pipes and filters.

I run

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
```

twice.

I opened the `conf.d` folder in Nautilus, but there wasn't a splash file. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, but still no splash file. I expected `FRAMEBUFFER=y` to be inside a splash file inside the conf.d directory, but instead of that a resume file is in the `conf.d` directory with a completely different line which is:

```
RESUME=UUID=d9da4acc-b432-4cc3-927a-5815aa2e1071
```

Is this going to be a problem?

Comment: sounds like your command didn't execute. were you prompted for a password?  run this command in a terminal: `sudo ls -l /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/`

Comment: Also, why would you use tee for that, rather than just doing something like `echo text > /etc/file` ?

Comment: when you do 'sudo command > file' the redirection takes place within your current shell, with your current permissions. By doing 'sudo tee' the file is opened with the permissions under the sudo.

In otherwords, the tee works, the echo wouldn't.

Comment: quack quixote, you were right! I was using ALT+F2 with run in Terminal marked and that way somehow sudo tee doesn't run. Now, I used Accessories -> Terminal instead and it run. Also, your sudo ls was listing only resume, but now it's listing splash too.